# Ionic firebase quota issue

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to use firebase authentication (Google and facebook) And firestore. I think its free so why i am recieving this error

```
Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Quota exceeded.
FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.
```

My auth service code

```
   onLoginSuccess(res: FacebookLoginResponse) {
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
    this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);

        this.fb.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', []).then(profile => {
        this.userData = {email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'], username: profile['name']}
        console.log(this.userData);
        console.log(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);

          let userData =  {
          email: this.userData.email,
          username: this.userData.username,
          photo: this.userData.picture,
          phone: '',
          point : '0',
        win : '0',
        lastLogin: new Date(),
          uID: this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
        };

//here the error start //
    const followDoc = this.angularFirestore.collection(`AppUsers`).doc(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).ref;

    return followDoc.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          console.log('old user');
          this.router.navigate(["/select"]);
      } else {
          console.log('new user');
          this.angularFirestore.collection('AppUsers').doc(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).set(userData);
          this.router.navigate(["/select"]);
      }
    }); 
//here the error end //

      })

  });
  }
```

I try to add my all code. What i am using in firebase is Facebook login, google login, cloud messaging, and for strorage firebase store. My total users are almost 300 now. I think facebook or google login is free so its not causing th problem.

Comment: Without seeing the specific code that generates this error, we can't really say what happened.  Please edit the question to include as much information as you can that you discovered in your own debugging.  Also indicate which pricing plan you're on as there are known limits that you should know about if you're in the free plan: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Which line of code generates the error?

Comment: comment where the error showing in code

Answer (score 0):

> //here the error start //
>
> const followDoc = this.angularFirestore.collection(`AppUsers`).doc(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).ref;

Looks like, you are over the quota in  database query/connection, not in the authentication.Probably you are over 100 connected users simultaneously

To see more:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/